# How do I remove Mr Handy

Tags: fallout-shelter

I'm trying to clear out my fallout shelter I've removed most settlers and most rooms. But I can't delete my last rooms because they have Mr Handys (Handies?). I have 5 exploring and can't send out any more.

Can I remove my excess Mr Handys?

Answer (score 2):

Not a defined way to remove them but when raiders/deathclaws attack, allow them to destroy one Mr Handy and move the one blocking you from removing rooms onto the top floor.

Unfortunately this will result in a permanent loss of one Mr Handy but there's really no other way.

Comment: I'll give this a try.